# Save Excel in CSV format using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to save excel in c# as .csv file. When I open the csv file the "-" is converted to some strange character. I have tried both .xlcsvwindows and xlcsv formats.
e.g. XXXXX2018 - OPS&FE.34AC becomes XXXXX2018 â€“ OPS&FE.34AC

```
xlWorkbook.SaveAs(outputFile, Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSV);
```

Comment: What are you opening it in? Open it in notepad or notepad++ and inspect it that way.

Comment: Try adding this before `SaveAs` - `Workbook.WebOptions.Encoding = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingUTF8;`